# Multiple file upload is uploading only last file and not the rest

Tags: java, php, android, file-upload

I have created an app which is supposed to upload all files from a particular directory, one after the other. The code is uploading only the last file in the directory and not all files.

**The activity class:**

```
public class UploadAudioDemo extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
    String selectedPath = "";

    ArrayList<String> selectedPathList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_audio_demo);



        openGalleryAudio();
    }

    public void openGalleryAudio(){

        String name = null;

        File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/My_records");
        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) 
        {
            if (f.isFile())
                name = f.getName();

            selectedPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/My_records/"+name;

            // Do your stuff
            Log.d("selectedPath", selectedPath);
            selectedPathList.add(selectedPath);
        }


        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {

                    }
                });                      
                Iterator<String> it = selectedPathList.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) 
                {
                    doFileUpload(it.next()+"");
                }

            }
        }).start();    

    }


    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload(String myFileUrl)
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://bumba27.byethost16.com/Tracker/Services/recordedAudio/file_upload_new.php?mb_code='mb_code1'";

        try
        {
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(myFileUrl) );
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);                 
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug","File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
            String str;

            while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
}
```

**The logcat report:**

```
/storage/sdcard0/My_records/10_12_2013_13_00_12.amr
/storage/sdcard0/My_records/10_12_2013_13_01_27.amr
File is written
Server Response The file is: 10_12_2013_13_01_27.amr and mb_code is: 'mb_code1'
File is written
Server Response The file is: 10_12_2013_13_01_27.amr and mb_code is: 'mb_code1'
```

From the logcat output we can understand that, while iterating the array, we are getting both the file links, but while uploading only the last file is getting uploaded.

**What am I missing out? How can this be rectified?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem after referring cYrixmorten's code. I had to make a small change in what cYrixmorten answered.

The edit in the openGalleryAudio() method:

public void openGalleryAudio(){

```
    String name = null;

    File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/My_records");
    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) 
    {
        if (f.isFile())
            name = f.getName();

        selectedPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/My_records/"+name;

        // Do your stuff
        Log.d("selectedPath", selectedPath);
        selectedPathList.add(selectedPath);
    }



    for(int z=0; z<selectedPathList.size();z++)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, FileUploader.class);
        i.putExtra("selectedPath", selectedPathList.get(z));
        i.putExtra("myFileUrl", selectedPathList.get(z));
        startService(i);
    }

}
```

**Instead of the iterator, I had implemented a simple for loop. The rest remains the same as cYrixmorten had answered.**

Comment: Nice you got it working! :) Could that have been the problem in the first place perhaps?

Comment: May be, but I am thankful to you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you use the same background Thread for all your uploads.

That is, it starts uploading file 1..n-1 but keeps getting interrupted with a new demand to upload the next n+1 file. The last file upload is not interrupted, hence succeed.

I would suggest looking into IntentServices: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

With an IntentService in place for uploading of files, you can do a simple loop over the files directly in your UI thread.

```
for (filesYouWantToUpload) {
     Intent i = new Intent(context, UploadIntentService.class);
     i.putStringExtra(file);
     startService(i);
}
```

**Edit:**

Cannot test the code, but it should look something like this.

The FileUploader IntentService:

```
public class FileUploader extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = FileUploader.class.getName();


public FileUploader() {
    super("FileUploader");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String selectedPath = intent.getStringExtra("selectedPath");
    String myFileUrl = intent.getStringExtra("myFileUrl");

    doFileUpload(selectedPath, myFileUrl);

}

 private void doFileUpload(String selectedPath, String myFileUrl)
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://bumba27.byethost16.com/Tracker/Services/recordedAudio/file_upload_new.php?mb_code='mb_code1'";

        try
        {
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(myFileUrl) );
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);                 
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug","File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
            String str;

            while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }

 }
```

Remember to update your manifest:

```
 <service android:name="yourpackage.FileUploader " />
```

Finally openGalleryAudio() would be something like this:

```
  public void openGalleryAudio(){

    String name = null;

    File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "/My_records");
    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) 
    {
        if (f.isFile())
            name = f.getName();

        selectedPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/My_records/"+name;

        // Do your stuff
        Log.d("selectedPath", selectedPath);
        selectedPathList.add(selectedPath);
    }



    Iterator<String> it = selectedPathList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, FileUploader.class)
        i.putExtra("selectedPath", selectedPath);
        i.putExtra("myFileUrl", it.next()+"");
        startService(i);
    }


}
```

Comment: Tried it out, but the result is the same, the last file is only getting uploaded. What can be done?